# Webflux - Transform a WebClient response globally

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm connecting to an API that responds to everything with a HTTP code 200 so I want to transform it correctly if it's a 4xx or 5xx. Is there a way to do this globally? with a ExchangeFilterFunction maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(
        clientResponse ->
            clientResponse
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .flatMap(
                    stringResponse -> {
                      var mutatedResponse =
                          clientResponse.mutate().headers(httpHeaders -> clientResponse.headers()).statusCode(calcNewStatusBasedOnStringResponse());
```